# Arbitrary number of fields in yasnippet

Tags: yasnippet

Is it possible in a yasnippet snippet to create an arbitrary number of fields following a template, stopping only once the user indicates they are done entering fields?

#### Example

One use case is to generate a Dart data class with an arbitrary number of member variables:

```dart
class MyDataClass {
  final Type1 field1;
  final Type2 field2;
  final Type3 field3;
  ...

  MyDataClass({
    required this.field1,
    required this.field2,
    required this.field3,
    ...
  });
}
```

Ideally this would work by yasnippet continuing to prompt for additional fields until I hit a key to stop the field entry loop.

Is this possible in yasnippet?

#### Research

The closest question I could find is [generating a template from strings](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19251/iterate-over-string-in-yas-snippet), but this is more or less custom elisp that happens to piggyback on yasnippet, rather than using facilities of yasnippet itself. Creating custom elisp for every snippet with aribitrary numbers of fields (something I would use often in many languages and contexts) seems to largely defeat the purpose of yasnippet, which is to make creating snippets almost as easy as writing code.